# hyperlink to record in LWC is showing recordId url

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I am using the below query to get task and lead details

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public static List<Task>  getRecords(){
    List<Task> latestTasks = new List<Task>();
    
    List<Task> taskList = [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, Status, Subject, TYPEOF who
                        WHEN Contact THEN Name
                        WHEN Lead THEN Id, Name, Company, Phone, Industry, CreatedDate, State , Country, Postalcode , Street, City
                        END
    FROM Task WHERE Type = 'Call Block' Order by CreatedDate DESC];
    system.debug('taskList ' + taskList);
    return taskList;
}
```

In LWC i am using datatable to display lead details

```
const columns = [
    { label: 'Company Name', fieldName: 'comLink', type: 'url', typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'Company' }, tooltip: 'Go to detail page', target: '_blank' } },
    { label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text', wrapText: true },
    { label: 'Address', fieldName: 'Address', type: 'text', wrapText: true },
    { label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'Industry', type: 'text', sortable: true, cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' } },
    { label: 'Date Added', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'date', typeAttributes: { timeZone: 'UTC', year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }, sortable: true },
];
```

I am trying to make Lead Company and Name to be hyperlink to record Id

```
  @wire(getTasks)
    tasks({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            let recs = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                let task = {};
                task.rowNumber = '' + (i + 1);
                task.comLink = '/' + data[i].Who.Id;
                task.Name = data[i].Who.Name;
                task.Address = data[i].Who.City + ' ' + data[i].Who.Street + ' ' + data[i].Who.State + ' ' + data[i].Who.Country + ' ' + data[i].Who.Postalcode;
                task.Industry = data[i].Who.Industry;
                task.CreatedDate = data[i].CreatedDate;
                task = Object.assign(task, data[i]);
                recs.push(task);
            }
            this.records = recs;
            this.showTable = true;
        } else {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
```

But i am getting the url link instead of Company Name. Any idea where it is going wrong.

[image]

Comment: Don't you need a `task.Company = data[i].Who.Company || data[i].Who.Name;`  inside your loop?

Comment: I am using task.comLink for Company data.

Comment: Yes, but `comLink` will give you the Url. In your column definition you say that the label is `Company`, which is not defined at the level of `Task`, and hence my feeling is that defaults to the url itself

Comment: I want to make Company as clickable , which will redirect to record Id when clicked.. Adding this task.Company = data[i].Who.Company || data[i].Who.Name;.. wont give me the recordId.

Comment: But you need to have the value you want to use as label somewhere. `fieldName` of the column would be `comLink` to give the "href" to the link. The `fieldName` of the `label` of the `typeAttributes` will give you the text to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your definition

```
{
  label: 'Company Name', 
  fieldName: 'comLink', 
  type: 'url', 
  typeAttributes: { 
    label: { 
      fieldName: 'Company' 
    }, 
    tooltip: 'Go to detail page', 
    target: '_blank' 
  } 
},
```

You are saying create a Column with label `Company Name`, of type `Url`. The link is defined in the field `task.comLink` and the label to show the link with is defined in the field `task.Company`

Your problem is that what you have in `task` does not contain a property called `Company` (hence, it falls back to the Url it self as label)

As mentioned on my comments, you could add under

```
task.comLink = '/' + data[i].Who.Id;
```

A line like

```
task.Company = data[i].Who.Company || "[ Not provided ]";
```

Alternatively, you could fetch also the company of the Contacts and use it as fallback in case you display a task for a Contact, so you would need to fetch that extra field (`Account.Name`) from the controller

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public static List<Task>  getRecords(){
    return [
        SELECT Id, CreatedDate, Status, Subject, TYPEOF who
            WHEN Contact THEN Name, Account.Name
            WHEN Lead THEN Id, Name, Company, Phone, Industry, CreatedDate, State , Country, Postalcode , Street, City
            END
        FROM Task 
        WHERE Type = 'Call Block' 
        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
    ];
}
```

And add under

```
task.comLink = '/' + data[i].Who.Id;
```

something like

```
task.Company = data[i].Who.Company || data[i].Who.Account?.Name || '[ Not provided ]';
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are on the right track, just one minor change

The `fieldName` should be name of the field which has the data not the label you are giving to the column.

**Change from**

```
{ label: 'Company Name', fieldName: 'comLink', type: 'url', typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'Company' }, tooltip: 'Go to detail page', target: '_blank' } },
```

**To**

```
{ label: 'Company Name', fieldName: 'comLink', type: 'url', typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'Name' }, tooltip: 'Go to detail page', target: '_blank' } },
```

So the overall columns become.

```
const columns = [
    { label: 'Company Name', fieldName: 'comLink', type: 'url', typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'Name' }, tooltip: 'Go to detail page', target: '_blank' } },
    { label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text', wrapText: true },
    { label: 'Address', fieldName: 'Address', type: 'text', wrapText: true },
    { label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'Industry', type: 'text', sortable: true, cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' } },
    { label: 'Date Added', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'date', typeAttributes: { timeZone: 'UTC', year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }, sortable: true },
];
```